# How can I write method for if dice gets same five random value, call it Yahtzee?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to make Yahtzee... but I have problem..how Can I write method for roll the dice and how can I write method for if all the dice have to be equal and call it Yahtzee.

```
public class YahtzeeDice {

    private final int DiceCount = 5;            // There are 5 dice in the game
    private final Die die;                      // But we only need 1
    private int rolledValues[];    // We roll it 5 times and record the values

    /**
     * This is the normal constructor for YahtzeeDice. It creates a new object 
     * and initializes the rolledValues by rolling the dice, since dice are always
     * showing some kind of value.
     * @param generator variable of type Random 
     */
    public YahtzeeDice(Random generator) {
        this.die = new Die(generator);
        this.rolledValues =  new int[this.DiceCount];
        this.RollDice();
    }

    /**
     * This constructor exists for unit testing purposes. You can create a new 
     * object with explicit values of each of the 5 dice. Useful for testing the
     * IsAYahtzee() method.
     * @param generator variable of type Random 
     * @param initialValues an array of initial dice values
     */
    public YahtzeeDice(Random generator, int initialValues[] ) {        
        this(generator); // call the other rconstructor                            
        for (int i = 0; i < this.DiceCount; i++) {
            this.rolledValues[i] = initialValues[i];        
        }
    }

    /**
     * Rolls all 5 Yahtzee dice. It should be implemented by rolling the 1 die
     * 5 times are recording the value of the roll 5 times.
     */
    public void RollDice() {
        //TODO: Implement this method here
       for(int i = 0; i < this.DiceCount; i++) {
           System.out.print((this.die.Roll() +1));
    }
    }
    /**
     * Checks for a Yahtzee condition - all 5 dice are the same value.
     * @return true when Yahtzee, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean IsAYahtzee() {
        // TODO: Implement this method here
        for (int i = 0; i < this.DiceCount; i++) {

        }
        return true; 
    }
    /**
     * Prints out the current values of the dice rolls for example if you
     * rolled a 1,5,3,2,2 it would return the String [1|5|3|2|2]
     * @return String representation of the dice values.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = "[";
        for (int i = 0; i < this.DiceCount-1; i++) {
            result += this.rolledValues[i] + "|";
        }
        result += this.rolledValues[this.DiceCount-1] + "]";
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//add dice rollsholder (e.g. below rolledValues[])

```
private int [] diceRolls = new int [5];
```

public void RollDice() {

```
   for(int i = 0; i < this.DiceCount; i++) {
       diceRolls[i] = (this.die.Roll() +1)
       System.out.print(diceRolls[i]);
}
```

}

public boolean IsAYahtzee() {

```
    for (int i = 0; i < this.DiceCount; i++) {

         if(i < (this.DiceCount-1) &&  diceRolls[i] != diceRolls[i+1] ){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: For loop can end on this.DiceCount -1 to simplify the code:`for (int i = 0; i < this.DiceCount - 1; i++) if(diceRolls[i] != diceRolls[i+1]) return false;`

Answer (score 0):

use the class Random (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) to generate randomnumbers. The comparison of the resulting dicevalues shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code :

- Declare a variable to hold the first value in your array.
- Loop through your array and compare all values to the variable value

  - if not equal, return false
- Exit loop, if you made it this far, return true

Micro-optimization, do not visit the first value in the array in your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit verbose, but to determine a Yahtzee, couldn't you just do

```
if ( this.rolledValues[0] == this.rolledValues[1] && this.rolledValues[1] == this.rolledValues[2] && this.rolledValues[2] == this.rolledValues[3] && this.rolledValues[3] == this.rolledValues[4] ) {
```

assuming you have five dice, of course.